# Is the Cherokee web server project stil alive?

Tags: web, cherokee

I've been trying to reach cherokee-project.com for a few days and nothing comes up.  Is this project still alive?

Answer (score 0):

Last commit was 4 months ago. Tweets and newsletters continue normally. Plus the [site](http://www.cherokee-project.com/) works for me. So I would say, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's alive.

The website works and there are development under "dev" branch on GitHub:

https://github.com/organizations/cherokee

Answer (score 0):

I think **the answer** is ***yes, it's still alive***. I've checked today (26/07/2013) and less than a month ago were commits to the master project.

Remember [qMail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qmail)?  it was SOO well done that after reaching version 1.0 only needed 3 minor fixes to be stable for almost a decade. So:

> "No recent commits" != "deprecated"

Answer (score 0):

This is 2013 and I see that there was a commit 7 hours ago. I wish there will be commits seven years after today.